# Query id return type

Tags: java, sql, spring-data

I use spring data. I want to get some contracts from DB. So I create two queries. In first I get contracts id that I need, in second I get contract by this id.

First query in Repository.class

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value =
        "select id from (" +
            "select contract.id, max(invoice.period_to) " +
            "from public.invoice " +
            "join public.contract on contract.id = invoice.contract_id " +
            "where invoice.period_to <= '2017-10-20' " +
            "AND contract.close_type IS NULL " +
            "AND contract.payment_type != 'TRIAL' " +
            "group by contract.id" +
            ") foo  ")
    List<Long> findContractsIdForInvoicesCreation();
```

ServiceJPA.class

```
List<Long> contractsId = ContractRepository.findContractsIdForInvoicesCreation();
List<Contract> contracts = contractRepository.findAll(contractsId);
```

But in last line above I have an error.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value element [2] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long (n/a)]

If I simply create

```
    List<Long> contractsIdL = new ArrayList<>();
        contractsIdL.add(2L);
        contractsIdL.add(3L);
        contractsIdL.add(4L);
    List<Contract> contracts = contractRepository.findAll(contractsId);
```

All works fine. Cant figure out what is wrong. In which type do first query return id?

p.s. id type in DB is bigint

p.p.s. I checked first query with System.out.println - it seems to return correct numbers.

Comment: Check what is in the array. Guess one of the values is not Long (e.g. null)

Comment: I cheked by System.Out.Println - is shows [2, 3, 4] - exectly what i need

Comment: Could it be the id values are not Longs but e.g. Integers. You may need to set result class

Comment: Mb its even not Int but Object?

Comment: Set additionally resultClass in your annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is with `ContractRepository.findContractsIdForInvoicesCreation();`

I think it doesn't return `List<Long>` as you expected